# Copy a file to remote server in Django

Tags: python, django, ssh

I created an API, that should copy a local file to a remote server.
I am doing this in Django.
I am using Spur to do this, but I can't connect to the remote server.

In the api call:

```
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="xx.xx.xx.xx",username="bla",password="bla",port=22)

result = shell.run(['echo', 'hello'])
```

I am getting the following error:

Error creating SSH connection
Original error: Server 'xx.xx.xx.xx' not found in known_hosts

But when I run the same code in a standalone python script I am able to connect and I am getting the result. Do I have to add something in Django settings?

Comment: Please add some code if you want some help

Comment: try adding the server xx.xx.xx.xx to your known_hosts file?

Comment: But I am able to connect with a standalone script that does the same thing. It is not connecting only when the API url is called from the browser (i.e., routed by Django)

Comment: Your standalone script runs from your ip, that has hostname in known hosts. You server probably does not.